# With Discord.py, is there a way to read embedded messages?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My code prints out the message the user sends. However, when an embedded message gets sent, there is nothing on the terminal and nothing is read.

Is there a way for my bot to read embedded messages along with normal messages on discord

Python 3.8

```py
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Do you use `on_message` function? Could you attach your code in your question?

Comment: added the code in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get list of embeds from message with `message.embeds`. [Link for docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#discord.Message.embeds). Try this solution:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    embeds = message.embeds # return list of embeds
    for embed in embeds:
        print(embed.to_dict()) # it's content of embed in dict
```

P.S. If your message has one embed you can use: `embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict()`