# Is there a way to read a value of a specific field in an embed discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: Embed]

So I have an embed like in the picture, I would like to get the user id from that embed, is there any way to do it?

What have I tried so far:

- to_dict [With Discord.py, is there a way to read embedded messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601894/with-discord-py-is-there-a-way-to-read-embedded-messages) Couldn't get to the value of the field
- .fields https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#discord.Embed.fields same result as to_dict
- .set_field_at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#discord.Embed.set_field_at didn't work, required me to change the value

Comment: Yes, there is. My question is - what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using embed.to_dict() but I couldn't get to value of that specific field, I tried to also use .fields and .set_field_at but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you add those approaches to your question please?

Comment: Can you elaborate each of the methods? Like what you did to try to get the value of the field, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_field_at()` is a function that will update the contents of a field. You will not be able to retrieve the contents with this method.

You can still use `.fields`. You can put something similar to the following in the method of your choice.

```py
embed = # Put the Embed in the picture as a discord.Embed object and assign it to this variable
for field in embed.fields: # Dynamically get the user id field.
    if field.name.lower() == "user id": # I recommend copying and pasting the field of choice, just in case the characters are not the same visually.
        user_id_field = field
        break
else: # In case the field isn't found
    pass # Put some code here
user_id = int(user_id_field.value) # Get the value of the field
# Either send or print it
```

**References:**

- [`discord.Embed.fields`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.fields) - Get a list of the fields from an embed.
- [`discord.Embed.add_field()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.add_field) - denotes the attributes from a field

Comment: Pretty sure that 'in' in 3rd line should be == since my code didn't work with in but worked with ==

Comment: @NimVrod I kept `in` just in case there are extra characters that you cannot visually see. But both are fine.