# discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to test if I can basically copy all messages sent to **test_copy_channel** channel and paste them to **test_paste_channel**
Though the bot is executing the commands and logging the embed correctly I keep getting an error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  global test_paste_channel, test_copy_channel
  test_paste_channel = bot.get_channel(868816978293452841)
  test_copy_channel = bot.get_channel(808734570283139162)
  print('bot is ready')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  # if message.author == bot.user:
  #   return

  if message.channel == test_copy_channel:
    await test_paste_channel.send(message.content)
    print(message.channel)

  if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    embed_var = discord.Embed(
      title= '''title''', 
      description= '''description''', 
    color= discord.Color.red()
      )
    
    embed_var.set_footer(text='footer')
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed_var)


bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

So what I do is send `!test` to **test_copy_channel** so the bot sends the embed then tries to copy my message and the embed
My message goes through fine but when the bot tries to copy the embed I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
⠀⠀File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
⠀⠀⠀⠀await coro(*args, **kwargs)
⠀⠀File "main.py", line 25, in on_message
⠀⠀⠀⠀await test_channel.send(message.content)
⠀⠀File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1065, in send data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
⠀⠀File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, in request
⠀⠀⠀⠀raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

It doesn't seem to stop the command from executing and the code seems to work properly.
As far as I understand, the error is triggered when it tries to copy the embed message that the bot have sent.
I just wanna know why it's triggering this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay what I think is happening is when you write :`!test` The `!test` is triggered in the other channel which in turn triggers the embed to come through the other channel as you have the line `if message.content.startswith('!test')` which is not channel specific.

However the problem that is occurring is  while the `on_message` event function gets called when the embed gets sent. The embed has no content so when you try send this out in the line `await test_channel.send(message.content)` The error occurs as the message.content is empty (as an embed is not content).

A cheat way of fixing this is just adding the line `if message.content:` above the `await test_channel.send(message.content)` as the embed gets sent through anyways due to `!test` being sent in the other channel.

Otherwise you should read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601894/with-discord-py-is-there-a-way-to-read-embedded-messages) to see how to get embed information out of a message (in brief its `embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict()`)

Hope this makes sense :).